# Why do I get serialization errors in calling events?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-debugging, events, hydrachain

I have put some events in my contracts like this

```
event TokenTransfer(address indexed sender,address indexed receiver,uint32 indexed num_tokens);
event ExceptionEvent(uint16 indexed retcode,address indexed userAddress,string context);
```

In my nodejs script I am doing something like this

```
iouContractInstance.TokenTransfer({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}).watch(function(blockWatchError, blockWatchResult){
    console.log("Looking out for Tokentransfer data");
    console.log("TokenTranfer Error:"+blockWatchError);
    if(!blockWatchError){
        console.log("The event data result is:"+blockWatchResult);
    }
});

iouContractInstance.ExceptionEvent({},{fromBlock:0,toBlock:'latest'}).watch(function(blockWatchError, blockWatchResult){
    console.log("Looking out for ExceptionEvent event data");
    console.log("ExceptionEvent Error:"+blockWatchError);
    if(!blockWatchError){
        console.log("The event data result is:"+blockWatchResult);
    }
});
```

On my node js console I get something like this

```
Looking out for Tokentransfer data
TokenTranfer Error:Error: Can only serialize integers
Looking out for ExceptionEvent event data
ExceptionEvent Error:Error: Can only serialize integers
Looking out for Tokentransfer data
```

Can somebody tell what am doing wrong?
My environment is:
Blockchain:hydrachain
Solidity:solc 0.2.0-1
Ubuntu 14:04

Comment: This might well be a bug in pyethereum, on which hydrachain is based. Can you verify if your event code does work with go-ethereum?

Comment: Bump, any news on this @codestruggle?

Comment: @Joel Hello Actually have'nt got time to concentrate on this right now though. I have a few pressing things to take care but as soon as I get time will look into this one.

Comment: I don't think it's hydrachain, i use geth and I saw this occasionally.   Unfortunately I can't remember how I fixed it.  Recompile?

Not sure `,string context` type maybe isn't something web3.js deals with correctly?

Comment: I'm starting to think this might be pythereum.  I saw this when I was using one of the testRPC implemenations I think.  I can't repro on geth.

Comment: I also recall having some similar issues when the ABI I was using differed from what was actually on the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround documented here:

https://gitter.im/ethereum/web3.js/archives/2016/01/09

Change the `fromBlock: 0` to `fromBlock: 'latest'` according to that chat.

AFAICT nobody has identified a root cause.

Also In my code I use all the `contract.allEvents` API and don't have a problem.  might try event dispatching your own particular events from that, or just parsing them from the txreceipt rather than using the event system at all.   I keep running into issues with the event system, so other than the allEvents to monitor a contract for debugging and analytics I don't use events at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try to implement and see.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the blockWatchResult variable will contains an object with many properties; in the .args property you should find your events parameters:
.args['sender'], .args['receiver']...